# Modify pandas dataframe cells by filtering datatime details

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataset with index, timestamp, and a value stored in three separate columns within a pandas data frame, e.g.:

[image]

I want to filter rows whose timestamp hours is equal to 23, and add a scalar to the values in the next column. How can I do this efficiently? The index column is not properly set in the dataset and I cannot rely on it.

Presently, I am using a for-loop to iterate over the rows, check if the hour in the timestamp is equal to 23, and modify the values in the corresponding cells, but it takes a lot of time. I tried to use the .groupby method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234770/filtering-pandas-dataframe-by-day) as below, but that seems not to be working. It operates on the data two times, leaving the data unchanged and throwing SettingWithCopyWarning. Here is what I try. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, though:

```
        for index, data_slice in df.groupby(df["Date"].dt.hour == 23):
            data_slice.loc["value"] += 1
```

Comment: okay got it, can you place the data as text please so we can copy that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why groupby, you can try:

```
df.loc[df['Date'].dt.hour==23, 'value'] += 1
```

Comment: This is so simple and brilliant. Thank you!